# How to delete some files after msi installation is completed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, windows-installer

I have a custom screen step displaying checkbox options for web.config specific to each environments (DEVINT, QA, Stage,Prod) as part of MSI installation.

Once the user selects QA as option then the web.qa.config file is renamed to web.config file 
After the complete installation, I see that there are other web.config files ( web.DEVINT.config,web.stage.config,web.prod.config) still present in the folder.

I want to remove the other web.config files web.DEVINT.config,web.stage.config,web.prod.config
after the installation is completed.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 0):

A RadioBox would seem a better choice then a Checkbox since I would imagine the choices are mutually exclusive.   Use the property associated with the control as conditions on the component so that only one of them gets installed.

Windows Installer will complain (ICE Valication) if multiple components install the same key path.  What I do to get around this is to make the keys paths go to a subdirectory such as Configs\Web.LifeCycle.Config so that each is unique.  Then I use the DuplicateFile table to clone that file to the real directory \ web.config path.  The downside is I deploy a subdirectory/file that isn't needed but the upside is I can use it to quickly know what was picked and have a backup of the file to compare against in case someone goes and modifies the real web.config.

In limited scenarios I use AppSearch to autodetect the life cycle instead of showing a UI at all.